# In Adonis.js Why refreshToken is null?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am learning Adonisjs and wanted to implement the logout part in my api rest, but I can't due to whenever I will logout refresh_token is requested in the request, but I don't know where this refresh_token comes from. I noticed that when I log in, I get a "requestToken" parameter, but it's null anyway

When I log in it works and returns something like to me:

```
   {
      "type": "bearer",
      "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTU3MTAxNTAwMH0.xXX6oDvdvdz59UJ2fstrFmOJEGP8luwKPtTeVF-Y224",
      "refreshToken": null
    }
```

Here's the code:

```
async login ({ request, auth }) { 
    const { email, password } = request.all()

    const token = await auth.attempt(email, password)

    return token
}

async logout({ request, response}) {
    const rules = {
      refresh_token: 'required'
    };

    const { refresh_token } = request.only(['refresh_token']);

    const validation = await validate({ refresh_token }, rules);

    const decrypted = Encryption.decrypt(refresh_token);

    if (!validation.fails()) {
      try {
        const refreshToken = await Token.findBy('token', decrypted);
        if (refreshToken) {
          refreshToken.delete();
          response.status(200).send({ status: 'ok' });
        } else {
          response.status(401).send({ error: 'Invalid refresh token' });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        response.status(401).send({ error: err.toString()});
      }
    } else {
      response.status(401).send(validation.messages());
    }

  } 
}
```

I tried to take a look at some git api or even adonisjs authentication documentation, but to no avail.

I also tried to add the token that is answered in request "request_token", but it returns invalid token:

```
{
  "error": "Invalid refresh token"
}
```

So, how can i solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per adonis doc, follow this api call - which generates refresh token during login - authentication flow

Instruct the JWT authenticator to generate a refresh token as well:

```
await auth
  .withRefreshToken()
  .attempt(uid, password)
```

Ref : https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the sample example as ref in the docs https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/authentication#_jwt but didn't work. got

```
await auth.withRefreshToken().attempt(uid, password)
```

output

```
     {
       "type": "bearer",
       "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTU3MTAxNTAwMH0.xXX6oDvdvdz59UJ2fstrFmOJEGP8luwKPtTeVF-Y224",
       "refreshToken": null
     }
```

instead use this

```
   if (await auth.attempt(uid, password)) {
       const savedUser = await User.findBy("uid", uid);
       await auth.withRefreshToken().generate(savedUser);
    }
```

output

```
 {
   "type": "bearer",
   "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTYzNDMyMjc2MywiZXhwIjoxNzIwNzIyNzYzLCJpc3MiOiJpc3MifQ.mj48h77eQQZfn7TjqyW_HDv5AIaTGtTabbID3J2Tnqw"
   "refreshToken": "d62308224c28a1569b0381c3f2f5b29fORSRBIdsHgfqHsqC+0RJQ3OCNZ/8/XW1NEq4AtEQTUfYonzodsqLUAy+e2sHsjIz"
 }
```